# Crystal report Error: "Memory Full. Not Enough memory for operation."

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, out-of-memory

I am using VS2013 and crystal report 2013

I am passing 30 parameters to crystal report.

It is working fine for 5 times, Then I got the next error:-

> Memory Full. Not Enough memory for operation.

What I tried so far:-

using `CrystalReport1.Refresh();` without solving the problem.

Appreciate any help.

**Edit 1:-**

I know maybe my question has lack of info but I think there is no any details could help you, any ways here you are the extra info I hope it will be useful.

I have Application as next:-

[image]

when I click Print it is working fine as next

[image]

if I close the window and press Print again it is working fine for 5 or 6 times,
then I faced the next error:-

[image]

**Edit 2:-**

My code is:-

1) Create new form and drag and drop crystal report viewer.

2) at the load event I wrote the next code:-

```
private void frmReport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("pName", PatientName);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("pAge", Age);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("pDate", Date);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("P1", Number1);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("P2", Number2);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("P3", Number3);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("P4", Number4);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("P5", Number5);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("P6", Number6);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("P7", Number7);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("pDrugsName1", DrugName1);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("pDrugsName2", DrugName2);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("pDrugsName3", DrugName3);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("pDrugsName4", DrugName4);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("pDrugsName5", DrugName5);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("pDrugsName6", DrugName6);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("pDrugsName7", DrugName7);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("pQTY1", QTY1);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("pQTY2", QTY2);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("pQTY3", QTY3);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("pQTY4", QTY4);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("pQTY5", QTY5);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("pQTY6", QTY6);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("pQTY7", QTY7);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("pTimeOfUse1", TimeOfUse1);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("pTimeOfUse2", TimeOfUse2);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("pTimeOfUse3", TimeOfUse3);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("pTimeOfUse4", TimeOfUse4);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("pTimeOfUse5", TimeOfUse5);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("pTimeOfUse6", TimeOfUse6);
        CrystalReport11.SetParameterValue("pTimeOfUse7", TimeOfUse7);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

and I am calling the form via next code:-

```
    DrugName1 = (txtDrugsName1.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : txtDrugsName1.Text;
    DrugName2 = (txtDrugsName2.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : txtDrugsName2.Text;
    DrugName3 = (txtDrugsName3.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : txtDrugsName3.Text;
    DrugName4 = (txtDrugsName4.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : txtDrugsName4.Text;
    DrugName5 = (txtDrugsName5.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : txtDrugsName5.Text;
    DrugName6 = (txtDrugsName6.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : txtDrugsName6.Text;
    DrugName7 = (txtDrugsName7.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : txtDrugsName7.Text;


    Number1 = (txtDrugsName1.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : "1";
    Number2 = (txtDrugsName2.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : "2";
    Number3 = (txtDrugsName3.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : "3";
    Number4 = (txtDrugsName4.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : "4";
    Number5 = (txtDrugsName5.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : "5";
    Number6 = (txtDrugsName6.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : "6";
    Number7 = (txtDrugsName7.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : "7";


    QTY1 = (cmbQTY1.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : cmbQTY1.Text;
    QTY2 = (cmbQTY2.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : cmbQTY2.Text;
    QTY3 = (cmbQTY3.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : cmbQTY3.Text;
    QTY4 = (cmbQTY4.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : cmbQTY4.Text;
    QTY5 = (cmbQTY5.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : cmbQTY5.Text;
    QTY6 = (cmbQTY6.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : cmbQTY6.Text;
    QTY7 = (cmbQTY7.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : cmbQTY7.Text;

    TimeOfUse1 = (cmbTimeOfUse1.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : cmbTimeOfUse1.Text;
    TimeOfUse2 = (cmbTimeOfUse2.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : cmbTimeOfUse2.Text;
    TimeOfUse3 = (cmbTimeOfUse3.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : cmbTimeOfUse3.Text;
    TimeOfUse4 = (cmbTimeOfUse4.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : cmbTimeOfUse4.Text;
    TimeOfUse5 = (cmbTimeOfUse5.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : cmbTimeOfUse5.Text;
    TimeOfUse6 = (cmbTimeOfUse6.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : cmbTimeOfUse6.Text;
    TimeOfUse7 = (cmbTimeOfUse7.Text == string.Empty) ? " " : cmbTimeOfUse7.Text;

    frmReport obj = new frmReport(
                                txtPatientName.Text, 
                                nudAge.Value.ToString(), 
                                dtpDate.Text,
                                DrugName1,
                                DrugName2,
                                DrugName3,
                                DrugName4,
                                DrugName5,
                                DrugName6,
                                DrugName7,
                                QTY1,
                                QTY2,
                                QTY3,
                                QTY4,
                                QTY5,
                                QTY6,
                                QTY7,
                                TimeOfUse1,
                                TimeOfUse2,
                                TimeOfUse3,
                                TimeOfUse4,
                                TimeOfUse5,
                                TimeOfUse6,
                                TimeOfUse7,
                                Number1,
                                Number2,
                                Number3,
                                Number4,
                                Number5,
                                Number6,
                                Number7
                               );
    obj.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: please make a [mcve] out of this. Chances are you can do something or you're making one hell of a memory leak or passing bad info.

Comment: @BugFinder, Thanks for commenting, hope the edit section set the question more clear, and feel free to ask about any other details.

Comment: No we need your code, not what your reports look like :P

Comment: how are you calling that form? are you sure its destroyed after use?

Comment: @BugFinder Simply via this code `frmReport obj = new frmReport( passing parameters)` then `obj.ShowDialog();`. Full code existing into question.

Comment: And I close the window from control box [X], as the usual of closing any form.

Comment: I tried a solution and it is solved the problem , into frmReport_FormClosing Type `crystalReportViewer1.Dispose();` and `CrystalReport11.Dispose();` - why these are not disposed after closing the form, I don't know, but this is the soluation of my case, @BugFinder Thanks for your time & Patient.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this worked for me too:

```
into frmReport_FormClosing Type crystalReportViewer1.Dispose(); and CrystalReport11.Dispose();
```